# JTable bloquear la modificacion de las celdas Java

Tags: java, java-swing

Quisiera saber como hacer para bloquear la modificacion de las celdas.

Comment: Declara la celda como no editable en tu modelo. Si miras la documentación de Java te lo explica muy bien. Creo que el `DefaultTableModel` viene ya sin poder editar a menos que implementes el método correspondiente.

Comment: pero cuando aplico eso, no permite selecionar una fila

Comment: como haria para poder seleccionar una fila o varias sin que se pueda editar las celdas

Answer (score 1):

Se puede hacer implementando el método `boolean isCellEditable(int row, int column)` de `DefaultTableModel`.

Como dices que lo que quieres es hacer editables unas filas y otras no, debes de implementar qué condición hace que sean editables/no editables y retornas con un `true`/`false`. **Pero se hace a nivel celda**. Luego puedes propagar el valor al resto de celdas para que sirva en toda la fila. Así sabrá que filas son editables y cual no.